# Safari cannot POST to iframe with https when basic authentication is stored in keychain

Tags: iframe, https, safari, basic-authentication

Need workaround for the following problem:

**Summary:**

See https://ecdip.ch/safaribug If https, a POST-request cannot be sent to target iframe.

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Go to https://ecdip.ch/safaribug
2. Log in DO NOT STORE IN KEYCHAIN
3. Try to send the form -> it works
4. Repeat 1 to 3 DO STORE IN KEYCHAIN -> form cannot be sent

**Expected Results:**

Sending the form (POST-request to hidden iframe) has to work if basic auth stored in keychain with https too.

**Actual Results:**

Sending the form (POST-request to hidden iframe) does NOT work with https when basic auth login stored in keychain

**Version:**

Bug exists in all version, OSX and Windows.

**Notes:**

The issues concerning http basic auth with Safari are discussed for years.

**Configuration:**

Does not occur in other browsers than Safari.